# Floating Label | Change Placeholder to Label On clicking the input field

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, css

on click of Input field Want Place holder to behave as label by moving up 
just look in the image when i enter first name the first name place holder moved up to become label 
how can i do it

register.cmp

```
<div class="tableData">


        <div class="FilterInput">
            <lightning:input type="Text" placeholder="First Name" value="{!v.con.FirstName}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="FilterInput">
            <lightning:input type="Text" placeholder="Last Name" value="{!v.con.LastName}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="FilterInput">
            <lightning:input type="Email" placeholder="Email" value="{!v.con.Email}" onblur="{!c.checkEmail}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="FilterInput">
            <lightning:input type="Email" placeholder="Re-enter Email Address" value="{!v.reEmail}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="FilterInput">
            <lightning:input type="tel"  placeholder="Phone" value="{!v.con.Phone}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="FilterInput">
            <lightning:input type="tel" placeholder="Mobile Phone" value="{!v.con.MobilePhone}" pattern="[0-9]{10}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="FilterInput">
            <lightning:input type="Text" placeholder="Fax" value="{!v.con.Fax}"/>
        </div>

        <div class="AccountHeading">Accounts to Enroll</div>
        <div class="FilterInput">
            <lightning:input type="Text" placeholder="Bill To Account Number" value="{!v.billToAccNo}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="FilterInput">
            <lightning:input type="Text" placeholder="Ship To Account Number" value="{!v.shipToAccNo}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="RSignIn">


            <span style="float:right;display:inline-flex">
                <lightning:button class="Buttongry" variant="brand" label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.cancel}"/>
                <lightning:button class="Buttonblue" variant="brand" label="Register" onclick="{!c.insertUser}"/>
            </span>
        </div>
   </div>
```

[image]

Comment: That would be improper use of a placeholder, you should really be using [`lightning:helptext`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:helptext/example).

Comment: can you tell with example please

Comment: Consider using [`lightning:recordForm`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordForm/documentation) for simple record inputs and saving